# Can Javascript functionality be broken by overlapping scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm currently working on an EJS webpage for a single module. In this framework, a set of default scripts are included for all modules, as well as a set of module-specific scripts. I can't change what is included.

I'm having issues getting a certain Highchart to be generated. Long story short, the common scripts included a Highchart library located at the framework's common library path. The module itself included a script to another Highchart library located at the module's local 3rd party library path. The name of these two scripts are different - I'm unable to tell if they are the same version whatsoever.

I'm in the process of troubleshooting but that's not the main point of this question. What I want to know is whether the existence of two different scripts of the same library being included in the same HTML page would cause problems?

Comment: There is a very high possibility that yes it will, but it might vary based on the library. jQuery handles it quite well - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/903324

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the library, and specially, what else is executed between the first and second time the library is being initialized.

Short answer is yes, it is very likely to cause problems.